# Get name from TableAttribute Linq2DB

Tags: c#, linq2db

I'm using `Linq2DB`, `LinqToDB.Mapping` to map the tables from database.

The class name has a Data Annotation named "Table" to specify the name of the table in de DB. For example:

```
[Table(@"EXAMPLE_ONLINE")]
public class Example
{
    [Column(@"ID_EXAMPLE")]
    public ulong IdExample { get; set; }
    [Column(@"DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get that table name from that Data annotation? Is tehere something like a

`Example.GetTableName()`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this information from `EntityDescriptor`:

```cs
var tableName = db.MappingSchema.GetEntityDescriptor(typeof(Example)).TableName;
```

Or you can create extension method:

```cs
public static GetTableName<T>(this MappingSchema mappingSchema) 
{
    return db.MappingSchema.GetEntityDescriptor(typeof(T)).TableName;    
}
```

Also `TableName` can be optined from `ITable<T>` interface:

```cs
var tableName = db.GetTable<Example>().TableName;
```